# Operator overlaoding in c++ = operator

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading

Following is a Node class with operator = overloaded(only showing self-assignment bit).

```
Node& operator=(const Node &other) {
        if ( this != &other) {
             // do stuff
        }
    }
```

My question is why do I need to explicitly type "&other", isn't "other" already a reference to a Node object? Also when I dereference "this" and compare as in:

```
if ( *this!= other )
```

it still will give an error. Is it because *this* is a const pointer to a Node object but 'other' is
a const Node object? Because even something like this won't work:

```
Node& operator=(const Node &other) {
    if ( (const Node)*this != other) {
            // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of the `&`, the address-of operator, in the test is taking the address of `other` and comparing that to the address that `this` contains. The test is determining whether `this` and `other` are referring to the _same_ object.

Comment: IOW, the code is checking for *self-assignment*, ie an object being assigned to itself, for example `Node n; n = n;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> isn't "other" already a reference to a Node object?

It is. And a reference **is not a pointer**. It's a direct alias for an object. When you interact with it you are interacting directly with the object, not with its address. A pointer to an object on the other hand is a container for an address. When you interact with the pointer you don't affect the object it points too, only the address. Instead you *dereference* it to get an alias to the object, and that's how you affect the pointee.

Therefore, on account of their differences, you cannot usually compare pointers and references. So to check for object identity you need to obtain the address from the references, and then compare it to the `this` pointer.

> Is it because this is a const pointer to a Node object but 'other' is a const Node object?

No, it's because `*this` obtains an alias to the object, while `other` already is. When you write `*this != other` you are trying to apply `!=` **to the objects themselves**, not to their addresses. Since there is likely no `operator!=` defined, you can't do the comparison. Nor do I suspect that you want to.

> Because even something like this won't work

`(const Node)*this` is dereferencing `this`, thus obtaining something that is *not a pointer* (but an object), and then attempts to cast the object to a pointer type. That is not something that the language supports implicitly. Hence the error.

Comment: But when you dereference a pointer, is it correct to say that, "now you have the object itself" or "now you have the alias for the object"? I've heard, "alias for the object" numerous times, so where's the actual object? Wasn't it stored in the address to which the pointer or the reference has?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it.

So 'other' is the Node object itself, but &other is the address of that Node object(or reference)?

Comment: @Shinji-san - *"now you have the object itself"* that's not a bad way to look at it, so you can say that yes. The actual object is somewhere in memory. You can have a name for it if it's a variable (the name itself can be thought of as another "original" alias), or no name in the case of dynamic allocation. So yes, it's at the address the pointer contains, but the address is not the object. Just like a sign that says "Lake" is not the lake itself, but only tells you where to find it.

Comment: @Shinji-san - Yes, you got it. `&other` is the address of the object that the reference provides an alias for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the check if the other node is the same as `this` node is only required if the `do stuff` part requires a lot of work and/ or the probability of using the `operator=` on the same node (i.e., `node = node`) is rather high.

So in order to check, if the other node is the same as `this` node you want to compare if the two nodes have the same address in memory. The comparison of the references to the nodes will, if it has been implemented, only compare if the two nodes have the same values.

The error for your second approach using the references might be that the comparison operator is not defined for your node class.